# Android synchronization (I think)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and have learned a lot with this project. I am almost there but, but one of my missing parts is... the game does something like the Simon Says game, and right now I am able to click on the Images and it also loops through them for the user but I can touch them while the loop goes through them. I want now to be able to set like a boolean flag that says userTurn if 0 then it's user turn and if 1 then its the system. Something of that sort.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the various states in which your application can be in is very large and/or complex, I would recommend the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). But if you just need two states, either system or user, I would use something like this:

```
private boolean isSystemTurn = false;
```

and then check it like that:

```
if (isSystemTurn) {
   // the user has to wait
} else {
   // it is user turn
}
```